# Javascript Array Hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to assign multiple parameters to each item in a Javascript array. In this case, `item 0` has a `val` of `1p` and a `pri` of `0.01`.

**Code:**

```
item[0][val]    = '1p';
item[0][pri]    = '0.01';
```

However, when running this code, I have the following console error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined
```

Is what I'm trying possible in Javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here `val` is the actual property so I think you need to use [Dot Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Dot_notation)

```
item[0].val = '1p'
item[0].pri    = '0.01';
```

Answer (score 1):

Either you call the variable with a dot notation (`.`) or call it marked between quotes.

Somthing like:

```
item[0]["val"] = '1p';
item[0]["pri"] = '0.01';
```

or

```
item[0].val = '1p';
item[0].pri = '0.01';
```

I'm recommanding the first method because this way you can define your object properties keys using hyphen too.